# REDHAT 7 yum update is not installing the packages on graphite, gtk3 and etc

Tags: yum, gnome

its REDHAT 7 server, i was trying to do the patch update in this server.

its not allowing me to the updates, throwing the errors.

most of the Gnome packages are not updating....

Kernel version: 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64

OS Release : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: graphite2-devel-1.3.6-1.el7_2.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
           Requires: graphite2(x86-64) = 1.3.6-1.el7_2
           Installed: graphite2-1.3.10-1.el7_3.x86_64 (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               graphite2(x86-64) = 1.3.10-1.el7_3
           Available: graphite2-1.2.2-5.el7.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               graphite2(x86-64) = 1.2.2-5.el7
           Available: graphite2-1.3.6-1.el7_2.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               graphite2(x86-64) = 1.3.6-1.el7_2
```

Please help me to resole this issue.

Thanks
Rameshkumar.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue just did below

```
sudo yum downgrade graphite2
```

this downgraded `graphite 2`to `graphite2-1.3.6-1.el7_2.x86_64`

Comment: its not working. After downgrade also i was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

enable ol7_optional_latest repository

```
[ol7_optional_latest]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Optional Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/optional/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Comment: Why we need to enable the Oracle Linux repo in Redhat 7 ? any particular reasons ?